# When creating and writing a txt file in c# and Unity, it only creates it and do not use it

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, save

I am making a game in Unity with c# as my main programming language. I try to make a new save.txt and autosave.txt if it doesn't already exist in the app folder. It can create it, but it doesn't work properly. Here are my codes:
Creating and writing a new save:

```
    void Start () {
    if(!File.Exists(Application.dataPath.ToString() + "/Save.txt"))
    {
        File.CreateText(Application.dataPath.ToString() + @"/Save.txt");
        saveFilePath = Application.dataPath.ToString() + @"/Save.txt";

        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFilePath, false);
        writer.WriteLine("10:21:59", "13 / 06 / 2017", "1", "1", "-21", "20000", "100", "500", "50", "20", "500","2","1","1","5000", "10");
        writer.Close();

    }
    if(!File.Exists(Application.dataPath.ToString() + "/AutoSave.txt"))
    {
        File.CreateText(Application.dataPath.ToString() + @"/Autosave.txt");
        saveFilePath = Application.dataPath.ToString() + @"/Autosave.txt";

        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFilePath, false);
        writer.WriteLine("00:00:00", "01 / 01 / 2017", "1", "1", "-21", "20000", "100", "500", "50", "20", "500", "2", "1", "1", "5000", "10");
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Here is my writing an existent .txt code:

```
    public void OnSaveGame()
{
    saveFilePath = Application.dataPath.ToString() + @"/Save.txt";
    isNewGame = false;

    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFilePath, false);
    theTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"); theDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    string ZeroPart = theTime + "," + theDate + ",";
    string FirstPart = income;
    writer.WriteLine(ZeroPart + FirstPart);
    writer.Close();

    SavingPanel.SetActive(true);
    Invoke("WaitTime",2);



}
```

I don't know what I do wrong.
P.S. In unity,if it helps, when I run it, it says that it "IOException: Sharing violation on path C:*\Assets\Save.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While both answers from @b00n and @martennis have some truth to them they are a bit lacking. Once the StreamWriter object had created the file merely closing the stream would not relieve the lock it has on that file. So when you're creating a new StreamWriter to access that file it throws the IOException because your new stream failed to acquire access since it's still being locked by the old one. Closing the stream and disposing it will ensure that the stream can do the proper cleanup required in order to release the file for subsequent reads. I'd highly suggest giving the File API documentation on MSDN a read to get a better understanding about how it functions and how to work with it.

EDIT: One way to ensure that a StreamWriter object is cleaned up is to use a using statement as @O. Matei mentioned. It would be something along the lines of the following:

```
using(TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFilePath, false))
{
    theTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"); theDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    string ZeroPart = theTime + "," + theDate + ",";
    string FirstPart = income;
    writer.WriteLine(ZeroPart + FirstPart);
    writer.Close();
}
```

The using statement is basically equivalent to a try-catch-finally with writer.Dispose() being called in the finally statement to ensure that even if an exception had occurred that the resources used had been properly cleaned up.

Answer (score 2):

File.CreateText returns a StreamWriter object. Since you are not using this object (or not disposing it before creating a new writer to the file), an exception is thrown because multiple objects have/want write-access to that file.

Please learn more about IDisposable and 'using' statements.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new StreamWriter, try to use the StreamWriter returned by `File.CreateText()`.